# Jupyter autoreload workflow

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to understand the best workflow for impotring script files into a jupyter notebook.

I have a notebook that does somethig like:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
import functions as F
```

Inside `functions.py`, I further do imports such as

```
import numpy as np
import mymodule
```

It seems then that, for example, numpy will get reloaded every time I execute a cell, which makes things a bit slow. How could I automatically reload `functions.py` without reloading the imports there that I never change?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by specifying the configuration option(`%autoreload 1`) to auto-reload a selected module.

However, the module must be imported as `%aimport my_module`.

Comment: Worth noting the *must*: `%aimport my_module as mm` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question. The main functionality of %autoreload is to automatically reload modules, what it does, according to you. You can read about it [here](https://switowski.com/blog/ipython-autoreload), I find it pretty well explained.

However, if you need to access import internals, you should take a look at [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) and especially **[importlib.reload()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#:%7E:text=importlib.reload(module))**:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(my_module)
```

or

```
from importlib import reload
reload(my_module)
```

It is available starting from Python 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I created an ipython extention that can be called like

`%reload_and_import my_module`

Is is the equivalent of writing the following lines

```py
from importlib import reload
reload(my_module)
from my_module import *
```

This extension/code block has to be run once in the jupyter notebook

```py
from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic
from IPython import get_ipython
import importlib
import sys
import os

# If you want to import files from another directory
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
import my_module1
import my_module2

@register_line_magic
def reload_and_import(line):
    """Reload the specified Python modules and import everything from them."""
    module_names = line.split()
    for module_name in module_names:
        if module_name in sys.modules:
            importlib.reload(sys.modules[module_name])
        else:
            print(f"No module named {module_name} is currently imported.")
            # __import__(module_name)
        # Import everything from the module into the global scope
        globals().update({k: v for k, v in importlib.import_module(module_name).__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('_')})

# This function is optional. It is used if you want to pre-import files
def pre_run_cell(info):
    """Function to be called before each cell execution. It calls the %reload_and_import magic command."""
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('reload_and_import', 'my_module1 my_module2')

# Register the pre_run_cell function to be called before each cell execution
get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', pre_run_cell)
```